# Create an object without a name in C++

Tags: c++, object, initialization, parameter-passing

In Java it is possible to do the following:

```
function(new Parameter());
```

In C++ I know that I could do:

```
Parameter p;
function(p);
```

But is it possible to do something like:

```
function(Parameter p);
```

in C++?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. By comparison to Java, you need to decide if you want to create it on the stack or on the heap. The former can have value semantics (behaves like an int -- copies/moves like an int, no polymorphic behavior), while the latter will have reference semantics (refers to the same object instance, can behave polymorphically, copy by cloning).

```
void ref( const X& x )       { x.do(); } // Reference semantics
void ptr( const X* const x ) { x->do();} // Reference semantics
void val( const X x )        { x.do(); } // Value semantics

int main()
{
    ref( X{} );     // Created on the stack
    ptr( new X{} ); // Created on the heap, but leaks!
    val( X{} );     // Created on the stack, moved rather than copied if available

    auto x = X{};   // Created on the stack
    ref( x );
    ptr( &x );
    val( x ); // Makes a copy of the object

    auto p = std::make_unique<X>(); // Created on the heap, doesn't leak
    ref( *p );
    ptr( p.get() );
    val( *p ); // Makes a copy of the heap object on the stack
}
```

Note: You can have polymorphic behavior *with* value semantics if you jump through some hoops. See, for instance, Louis Dionne's talk at CppCon17 on [Runtime Polymorphism](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gVGtNFg4ay0). If you don't jump through these hoops but try to use a value object polymorphically, you can end up with object slicing.

Answer (score 7):

Yes you could do such a thing. As this is a temporary variable you don't need to name it, just as you did in Java.

The syntax will be:

```
function(Parameter());
```

If the class need parameter you just pass it to the temporary variable constructor:

```
function(std::string("hello"));
```

And finally, what you wrote for Java will work in c++ as well:

```
function(new Parameter());
```

But this will allocate the Parameter object on the heap, and in order to avoid memory leak, you will have to delete it inside function. But this is usually a bad idea.